# SQL Server 2012 installation Reporting Services Catalog error

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I'm installing SQL Server 2012 at the moment and when I was about to run the installation, this error pops up:

[image: The errors can be seen clearly in this picture]

On clicking the first failed test, which is "Reporting Services Catalog Database File Existence", this is what i get:

[image]

On clicking the second failed test, which is "Reporting Services Catalog Temporary Database File Existence", this is what i get:

[image]

So basically, both of the message box says me that "Catalog Database File" & "Catalog Temporary database files exists". Because of this, i need to select Reporting Services file-only mode installation.

My questions are:

1. How do i select file-only mode installation?
2. Do i've to close the setup and do something and afterwards run the setup again?

Btw, I had SQL Server 2012 installed before. I uninstalled it completely due to some strange errors and decided to reinstall a fresh copy of SQL Server 2012 and now I'm stuck with these errors. Any help will be sincerely appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you gone through the steps on this page from MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281380(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks but i checked that link a few minutes ago but the problem was the files already existed and the SQL Server 2012's Setup creates them on the pc it's currently being installed, I guess it's not set to work with pre-installed version of those Files. That's why these two tests were failing. But it's fixed now, BhupeshC's solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Since you already had one installation of SQL Server done before, there was a database already created. That **did not** get removed. So when you reinstall, its trying to create the database with the same name, hence, the error. You need to delete the old files to continue the new installation.

> From the direcotry
>
> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`
>
> Remove the following files
>
> - `ReportServer.mdf`
> - `ReportServer_log.LDF`
> - `ReportServerTempDB.mdf`
> - `ReportServerTempDB_log.LDF`

[image: Screenshot]

Try the Following link for further help.

**[Reporting Services Catalog Error.](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/07/05/sql-server-fix-rule-reporting-services-catalog-database-file-existence-failed/)**

---

For [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) the path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQL2012\MSSQL\DATA
```

where `MSSQL2012` is the instance name and the respective file names are:

- `ReportServer$MSSQL2012.mdf`
- `ReportServer$MSSQL2012_log.mdf`
- `ReportServer$MSSQL2012TempDB.mdf`
- `ReportServer$MSSQL2012TempDB_log.mdf`

Comment: Hi. This post and solution really helped me a lot of hours. Thank you!

Comment: Exact same problem exact same solution.

Comment: this fixed my problem as well. Thank you

Comment: had the exact same problem just now while installing in another machine haha

Comment: Thanks. I was reinstalling Sql Server 2008 R2. Deleting the old files resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the following files from the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` directory:

```
bulletReportServer.mdf
bulletReportServer_log.LDF
bulletReportServerTempDB.mdf
bulletReportServerTempDB_log.LDF.
```

This happens if you reinstall SQL Server and these files weren't deleted.

Comment: For me it was in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA